# How to render the viewport with EEVEE and the "final" render with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I want to render the viewport with EEVEE and the "final" render with Cycles.
Since Blender took so many changes in the Alpha phase, all how-to videos
about blender 2.80 show panels, buttons and so, which have changed.

So, where is the switch to configure Blender to render the viewport with EEVEE while the final renders remain based on Cycles?

Answer (score 1):

The viewport is chosen automatically based on which shading mode you are in no need to do any additional setup.

For [LookDev](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123164/what-is-lookdev-mode-for-in-2-8), and *Rendered* modes it uses EEVEE is used automaticaly, for other modes the Workbench engine is used.

To pick your current render engine used for image output go to the *Properties Window > Render*, tab and pick your engine from the list.

[image]

Comment: "For LookDev, and Rendered modes it uses EEVEE" - maybe this has changed in recent versions but it doesn't seem to work like this. you set a render engine and that's the one that's used in rendered mode (in the viewport) or when you render the scene. so what i think op asked was if it's possible to select one engine to use in the viewport when it's in rendered mode and another one when doing the actual render.

Comment: No that is not possible as far as I know. Rendered view uses the render engine setup for rendering

Comment: thanks! your answer is actually correct though. regarding op's question you can just use eevee by setting the viewport shading to "material preview" and enabling both "scene lights" and "scene world" lights. this will effectively render using eevee settings. then you can select cycles as your ender engine for the actual render. (see [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html#settings))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your viewport rendered with Eevee, you just need to select *Material Preview* in the *Viewport Shading* setting, and check *Scene lights* and *Scene world*, like this:

[image]

Then in the *Render properties* you have to select *Cycles* as your *Render Engine*.

[image]

Thanks to this configuration, you will use *Cycles* in your final renders and *Eevee* in your viewport.