# 2.8 Viewport and Render Preview

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

My Viewport in Eevee looks nice and how I want it (LookDev shading).
However, the render preview looks nothing like what I have done and I don't know how to change it to look the same as lookdev. 
Devlook is that thing at the top right of the 3d space with 4 buttons.

LookDev
[image: lookdev shading]

Render preview
[image: viewport render]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is LookDev mode for in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123164/what-is-lookdev-mode-for-in-2-8)

Answer (score -1):

It is because LookDev don't care about lighting, materials,etc. It just gives the quick view of how render will look.
So first of all add a lamp to viewport by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and click Lamp>Sun, Grab it by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> and take it on top of your object.
Edit:
I missed out to look the rendering engine you have selected, It should be Cycles. Change it to Cycles by going to render settings and click on Rendering engine dropdown and select Cycles.

> EEVEE is not capable to show reflections and stuffs.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89484/discussion-on-answer-by-yash-2-8-viewport-and-render-preview).